# How to render links in a template for database filtering in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using the "keyone" column in the database to filter entries. So far in the code i have written i am successfully able to render template with "keyone = 2" values. what should i write in a new template file, and how should i modify existing views.py so that when the template file renders it contains a list of links , each link for each value of "keyone" , when i click on the link say "keyone = 2", the selected entries should get rendered in home.html

models.py

```
# app/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse # new

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:50]
    keyone = models.IntegerField(default = '777')

    def get_absolute_url(self): # new
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

views.py

```
def HomePageView(request):
    key2select = Post.objects.filter(keyone=2)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'key2select': key2select,
    })
```

home.html

```
<ul>
  {% for post in key2select %}
  <li>{{ post.keyone }}&nbsp &nbsp{{ post.text }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

sample database
[image: sample database]

desired rendering
[image: desired rendering]

Comment: Is this what are you looking for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, we need to get all keyone values in the DB, to be passed to home.html.
Then in home.html, we need a navbar or somewhere else to put all these links which represent all the keyone values.

So the code would be like:

models.py

```
# app.models.py would remain the same
```

views.py

```
def homePageView(request, key):
    key2select = Post.objects.filter(keyone=key)
    keyones = Post.objects.distinct('keyone')
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'key2select': key2select,
        'keyones': keyones
    })
```

You can check the distinct() in the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/) to get distinct values of a column in DB

home.html

```
<!-- home.html -->
<nav>
    <ul>
        {% for key in keyones %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'app:home' key%}">somthing {{key}} something</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
...
<ul>
  {% for post in key2select %}
  <li>{{ post.keyone }}&nbsp &nbsp{{ post.text }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

As we passed the key to the url in the nav link, we need to change the url pattern to catch this.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    ...
    path('home/<int:key>/', views.homePageView, name='home')
    ...
]
```

Comment: thanks, this is just what i wanted. i will workout some errors i am getting and let you know if it worked.

Comment: just one change keyones = Post.objects.values_list('keyone',flat=True).distinct(), i have posted the complete code below, thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helps. I knew there would be some problem with the distinct() method, as I was not sure which SQL you use, anyway, I am glad you figure it out yourself, that's the best.

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm not understand you problem, if you'r looking for create a list of link code should be

```
<ul>
   {% for post in key2select %}
       <a href="{% url "post_detail" post.id %}"><li>{{ post.keyone }}&nbsp &nbsp{{ post.text }}</li><a/>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This will contain every post link with list item

Comment: yes you did not understood the problem completely, my fault i did not give a sample database , i have edited the original question

Answer (score 0):

thanks @sheng-zhuang for providing the solution. Here is the working code with some slight modifications for my benefit.

I created a new template select.html and here is the logic -

Views.py

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

def SelectView(request):
    keyones = Post.objects.values_list('keyone',flat=True).distinct()
    return render(request, 'select.html', {
        'keyones': keyones
    })

def HomePageView(request, key):
    key2select = Post.objects.filter(keyone=key)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'key2select': key2select,
    })
```

index.html

```
<header>
  <a href="{% url 'select' %}">Select</a><br />
  <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}">Post</a>
</header>
```

select.html

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        {% for key in keyones %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'home' key%}">Keyone value = {{key}} </a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

home.html

```
<header>
  <a href="{% url 'select' %}">Select</a><br />
  <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}">Post</a>
</header>
<br /><br /><br /><br />

<ul>
  {% for post in key2select %}
  <li>{{ post.keyone }}&nbsp &nbsp{{ post.text }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

urls.py

```
   path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
   path('select/', SelectView, name='select'),
   path('home/<int:key>/', HomePageView, name='home')
```